# jboss server LDAP realm not working

Tags: security, ldap, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to configure a J2EE application running on my local jboss EAP 6.1 server to use a Microsoft AD LDAP for authentication.  What I have isn't working, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

If I define a user within the application-users.properties file, I can authenticate.

Here is my web application's web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp" version="3.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.company.test.project.servlet.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <security-constraint>

  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Secured Resources</web-resource-name>
   <description>All CrossSells resources not viewable by the public</description>
   <url-pattern>/test.do</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
   <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>

  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>DV_User_1</role-name>
   <role-name>DV_User_2</role-name>
   <role-name>DV_Super_User</role-name>
   <role-name>DV_Admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>

 <login-config>

  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>LdapRealm</realm-name>

  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/jsp/login.jsp</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/jsp/error.jsp?message=Invalid+Username+or+Password</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>

 </login-config>

 <security-role>
  <role-name>DV_User_1</role-name>
 </security-role>

 <security-role>
  <role-name>DV_User_2</role-name>
 </security-role>

 <security-role>
  <role-name>DV_Super_User</role-name>
 </security-role>

 <security-role>
  <role-name>DV_Admin</role-name>
 </security-role>

 </web-app>
```

and here's the security settings in my jboss EAP server's standalone.xml:

```
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="LdapRealm">
            <authentication>
                <ldap connection="MicrosoftAD" base-dn="DC=co,DC=company,DC=local">
                    <advanced-filter filter="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
                </ldap>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <outbound-connections>
        <ldap name="MicrosoftAD" url="ldap://server:389" search-dn="CN=server\, server,OU=Service Accounts,OU=POD,DC=co,DC=company,DC=local" search-credential="password"/>
    </outbound-connections>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Management interfaces change security-realm="managementRealm" for security-realm="LdapRealm"

@braybaut